# Fan controlled By heat.

Tags: sensor, heat, fan, thermistor, cooling

I need to make a computer fan powered by 12v that turn on when the heat is like over 40 degree and to power off if the heat drops down.

I asked in many Facebook pages and some told me i need a thermistor, and no body have a clue what type of thermistor that works for this solutions.

Any help please.

Comment: The thermistor is only the sensor that can be used to measure the temperature.  You will still need a control circuit to decide when to turn the fan on and off and some sort of switch to control power to the fan.  Is the fan internal or external to the computer?  Where do you intend to measure the temperature: ambient air, on the computer surface, or internal to the computer? How much current does the fan draw?  As you can see, you need to provide more information in order to get a useful answer to your problem.

Comment: Computer motherboards generally have this functionality built-in. Since you're obviously not an EE, I'm going to refer this to Superuser.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple thing you could do is buying a 40°C bimetal thermoswitch (normal open) and wire it in series with your fan. They are about 0,20 to 3 Euro a piece.
[image: Bimetal switch]

https://www.google.de/search?q=bimetallschalter+40%C2%B0C&tbm=shop